# Start a new thread with context android

Tags: android

I have inherited ImageView class for my custom image. Every thing works fine. In my inherited class I create 25 rects, 25 paint and 25 colors. See below

```
private Rect[] rect = new Rect[25];
private Paint[] paints = new Paint[25];
private int[] colors = new int[25];
```

I initialise the above variables inside a loop in my constructor. Everything works fine.

But now I use this imageview in a listview. But when I scroll there is a small lag, Its not that smooth.

So I am planning to move the assigning part to a different thread. But here I have only a context and not an activity. How to start a background thread from a context? Also I will need to update the image in uithread.

Comment: why do you need context to start a thread?

Comment: @mmlooloo I don't have an activity instance. I have only a context. So nothing is required? If I use new Thread() will it work?

Comment: yes, why not? to start a thread you do not need activity, you need process, I think you confused activity and process.

Comment: @mmlooloo. Okay I will try it and let you know